# Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found -- Could not fix it in windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to run the following script:

```
def plot_pretty(dpi=175,fontsize=9):
    # import pyplot and set some parameters to make plots prettier
    plt.rc("savefig", dpi=dpi)
    plt.rc("figure", dpi=dpi)
    plt.rc('font', size=fontsize)
    plt.rc('xtick', direction='in') 
    plt.rc('ytick', direction='in')
    plt.rc('xtick.major', pad=5) 
    plt.rc('xtick.minor', pad=5)
    plt.rc('ytick.major', pad=5) 
    plt.rc('ytick.minor', pad=5)
    plt.rc('lines', dotted_pattern = [0.5, 1.1])
    plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
    return

plot_pretty(dpi=250, fontsize=9)
```

But when i try to plot I get the following error:

```
Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

I know that there a re relevant questions here, but none of the answers seem to solve th problem for a windows environment. Any help?

Comment: Do you have a tex distribution like texlive or miktex installed?

Comment: Yes I do! Thanks for the help!